# Problemas al asignar valor a textBox después de llamada AJAX

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Tengo un vista en donde listo varios productos. a través de una llamada AJAX y en evento OnChange, consulto el valor de ese producto para mostrarlo en un textBox.

El valor del producto lo rescato sin problemas, mi problema es al momento de asignarlo ya que asigna el mismo precio a todos los productos. Se que es debido a que comparten la misma clase de CSS.

¿Cómo puedo capturar la posición del Select con el que estoy trabajando para que no se asigne a todos los productos?

[image: Listado de productos]

Este es mi método de JS

```
function setProduct(id) {
$.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  url:"http://localhost:3000/products/" + id,
  dataType:"json",
  success: function(respuesta) {
    producto = document.getElementsByClassName('producto');
    inputPrecio = document.getElementsByClassName('precio');
    for (let i = 0; i < producto.length; i++) {
      $(inputPrecio[i]).val(respuesta.pro_costo);
      //document.getElementsByClassName('precio').value = respuesta.pro_costo;
      console.log(respuesta.pro_costo);  
    }

  }
})
```

}

Comment: Si la función se invoca por un evento, podrías definir tu función como `setProduct(id, event)` y luego llamar a `event.target` para poder saber desde donde se generó el evento y así eventualmente saber cual es la fila padre que tiene como hijo el select que acaba de cambiar.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo resolví como me lo dijiste, use event.target para llegar al inputText de la fila actual

Comment: Me alegro por ti. Agrega tu solución como respuesta por si eventualmente le sirviera a alguien que tuviese tu misma duda. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que me hacía falta era asignar el precio al input. Lo logre de la siguiente manera

```
function getPrice(id, event) {
    $.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url:"http://localhost:3000/sales/getPrice/" + id,
      dataType:"json",
      success: function(respuesta) {
        inputPrecio = event.target.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('precio');
        $(inputPrecio).val(respuesta[0].precio);

      }
    })
  }
```